# how to use redis in mongoose toJSON properly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, redis

I want to check if coinObject.coinid exists in redis or not, if so I want to add online value to my object with reply value if it is null I want to set coinObject['online'] to 0.

But this cod does not work at all, When I try to add some dummy data out of client.get method , it works, it returns properly but I want to do that depending on coinid property of every object, thanks

```
  coinScheme.methods.toJSON =  function (){
        const coin = this
        const coinObject = coin.toObject()
        
       client.get(coinObject.coinid,async (err,reply)=>{
        
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            if(reply!=null){
                coinObject['online'] = reply
            }else{
                coinObject['online'] = 0
            }
           
        })
        return coinObject
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running an asynchronous function (`redis.get`) inside of a synchronous function (`toJSON`). You can use either promise or callback to solve it:

```js
// callback version
// example: instance.toObjectAsync((err, coin) => console.log(err, coin))
coinScheme.methods.toObjectAsync = function (callback) {
    const coin = this.toObject();
    client.get(coin.coinid, (err, reply) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        coin.online = reply === null ? 0 : reply;
        callback(null, coin);
    });
};


// promise version
// example const coin = await instance.toObjectAsync();
coinScheme.methods.toObjectAsync = async function () {
    const coin = this.toObject(),
        reply = await client.get(coin.coinid);

    coin.online = reply === null ? 0 : reply;
    return coin;
};
```